# Is there a way to write a for each in python3 that modifies the array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say for example that I have an array that represents a name and I want to use just the first letter of any part of a name that is not the first or the last part:

```py
# Have
name = ["John", "Banana", "Doe"]

# Want
["John", "B", "Doe"]
```

Can I iterate through a subset of an array and change the variables inside it through the variable that references it like so?

```py
for part in name[1:-1]:
    part = part[0]
```

The only solution I fould for this was to use list comprehention, but it was too hard to read:

```py
name = [part if i in [0, len(name)-1] else part[0] for i, part in enumerate(name)]
```

Comment: comprehension can indeed be confounding.  maybe bury it in an appropriately named function or use comments.  you could also use numpy arrays of dtype object instead of lists for an alternate syntax, but additional dependencies is worse than keeping the confoundation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v = v[0]` reassigns the name `v`, that was previously bound to one of the list elements. This does not mutate the list, though.

You could fix your loop by iterating over an index range and explicitly reassign list elements.

```
for index in range(1, len(name) - 1):
    name[index] = name[index][0]
```

---

An easier to read list-comprehension solution would be:

```
name[1:-1] = [v[0] for v in name[1:-1]]
```

---

An equivalent solution without a list comprehension would be:

```
new_values = []

for v in name[1:-1]:
    new_value = v[0]
    new_values.append(new_value)

name[1:-1] = new_values
```

---

Bonus: repeating `[1:-1]` twice is not as clean as it could be. You could define a slice object to refer to the desired part of the list, e.g.

```
where = slice(1, -1)
name[where] = [v[0] for v in name[where]]
```

Comment: What is the point of building up a list to assign to a slice when you can just do the individual assignments directly (as in your first solution)?

Comment: @ScottHunter educational reasons. OP is new to python and finds list comprehension hard to read.

Comment: I thought OP meant that comprehension in particular; yours was about as straight-forward as one could get.

Answer (score 1):

```
start = 1
for i,v in enumerate(name[start:-1]):
    name[i+start] = v[0]
```

Or something slightly cleaner, using what I just learned about `enumerate`:

```
start = 1
for i,v in enumerate(name[start:-1],start):
    name[i] = v[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `enumerate` with a `set`?

```
name = ["John", "Banana", "Doe"]

pos = {0, len(name)-1}

[w if i in pos else w[0] for i,w in enumerate(name)]
```

or with a classical loop (but without explicit check, the list should have more than 1 element):

```
out = name[:1]

for i in range(1, len(name)-1):
    out.append(name[i][0])

out.append(name[-1])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
for i,v in enumerate(name[1:-1]):
   name[i] = v[0]
```

What you can't do while iterating over a list is changing the list  size, but changing the content is allowed.

Comment: Not if you want OP's desired result.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Did you actually try this & check the results?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work

Comment: Another problem with this approach is that the `i` starts at 0, but the iteration starts at 1. You would need to use `name[i+1]` to make it work.

Comment: You just need to pass a value of 1 as the second argument to enumerate and this will work

Comment: @JoãoFukuda: That is *the* problem; what other did you find?

Comment: enumerate has an optional `start` parameter that you can use.

Comment: @ScottHunter: Not sure what you meant by that...

Comment: @JoãoFukuda: "Another problem" suggests, well, another problem; I was asking what you thought that was.

Comment: @ScottHunter: Oops, sorry for the missunderstanding. "A problem with this..." is what I wanted to say.